# How to use IdentityIdentityServer4 and ASP Identity Provider with MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I was wondering if anyone had a good solution to using both ASP.NET Core 3 Identity and IdentityServer4 with MongoDb as the backend. I've had some success with the MongoDb QuickStart example for MongoDb. Unfortunately it uses TestUsers in memory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the Community quickstarts & samples: [IdentityServer4 samples for MongoDB](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/community.html#identityserver4-samples-for-mongodb)

Comment: Sorry. Not even close. However a few sections down is one that is closer but still no cigar (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/aspnet_identity.html). I'm looking to implement identity using MongoDb. My IdentityServer4 portion is already working nicely using MongoDB and test users. SQL doesn't seem to work as claimed in Docker/K8S, so that is why I am using MongoDb.

Comment: I'm getting a little closer with this. https://github.com/alexandre-spieser/AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore

Answer (score -3):

To use users from MongoDB with IdentityServer4, you need to implement IProfileService as per [this document](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html)

Comment: Why? You can use any database without having to implement the ProfileService. I see no explanation in your answer nor in the provided link.

Comment: This comment is misleading. One can definitely implement IdSvr with MongoDB without ever using an implementation of IProfileService.